# different between UNIQUE_FIELDS and UniqueValidator

Tags: validation, django-rest-framework

What is different in django rest framework between `UNIQUE_FIELDS = 'field'` and `UniqueValidator()`  in terms of view of determining the uniqueness of a field? And is there this difference?

Comment: what's UNIQUE_FIELDS = 'field' ?

Comment: @Linovia when you declare a model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One is for the model and the other for the serializer. The former will enforce it to the database level while the latter will make an explicit check during validation - whether or not this constraint exists in the database.

`UniqueValidator` will be set by the `ModelSerializer` during the introspection pass.

You may choose to dismiss it to avoid extra queries and handle the constraint from the DB by yourself for example. You may also set it to ensure uniqueness for the incoming data even if it's not enforced on the DB level.

Comment: That is, if there is a limit at the DB level, then validator does not make sense?

Comment: if there's a limit as the DB level and no validator, then you'll get a HTTP 500 saying that the request broke a constraint in the DB. Go figure which field is guilty if you have several constraints

Comment: note that your comment falls in the "You may choose to dismiss it to avoid extra queries and handle the constraint from the DB by yourself for example." part ;)

Comment: one more question(thanks ;) ):
then what is different btw `UNIQUE_FIELDS = 'field'` and `field = LowerCharField(max_length=255, ..., unique=True)` when declaring a field?
i don't understand it

Comment: I need a pointer to that UNIQUE_FIELDS. I understood it as if you were referring to unique=True.